# solc inside firebase functions causes deployment error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I need to compile a smart contract inside a firebase function. I am using solc `"solc": "^0.8.13",` in my `package.json`.

Code of the firebase function responsible to create the contact is;

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require("fs");
const Web3 = require('web3');

exports.createSC = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) return { data: data, status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in' }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            admin.auth().getUser(data.owner)
                .then(userRecord => {

                    //below function compiles the contract and returns abi/binary code etc
                    let contract = instantiateContract('sources/SnaphashToken.sol');
                    //use web3 to actually deploy contract
                    let web3;
                    //...code emitted...
                    resolve(contractDeployResult)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error)
                    reject({ status: 'error', code: 500, error })
                })
    });
})
```

this works perfectly well when deployed on functions simulator locally but when deployed on firebase cloud I get this exception;

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function ethereum-createSC(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        ethereum-createSC(us-central1)
```

When I comment out `const solc = require('solc')` in my function, it deploys without problems. I really need to be able to deploy smart contracts after modifying based on user input and would appreciate a help on it

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the subject function was causing deployment error because of `Error: memory limit exceeded`. I was able to see that after I checked detailed logs of the functions with `firebase functions:log`

```
2022-05-27T17:09:27.384860094Z E ethereum-createNft: Function cannot be initialized. Error: memory limit exceeded.
```

In order to fix this issue, I increased memory for the function from default `256MB` to `1GB` and `timeoutSeconds` from default 60 seconds to 120 seconds

```
exports.createNft = functions.runWith({memory:'1GB',timeoutSeconds:120}).https.onCall((data, context) => {
..code here..
});
```

And then deployment was successful